# How to bring characters from 2 function and produce an output?

Tags: java, string, function

This is only a code snippet of the code I am currently working on. This code accepts `& and |` and `0 and 1` as input. It is producing a series of strings i.e. ||| to &&& and a series of integers 000 to 111.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String a;                         //CODE PRODUCING ||| TO &&&
        for(int i=3;i<=3;i++) {
            String p="";

            for(int j=0;j<=i;j++) {
                for(int m=0;m<j;m++) {
                    p=p+"&";    }
            for(int m=0;m<i-j;m++) {
                p=p+"|";    }
            printAllPermutations(p);
            p="";
            }

       int n=3;                          //CODE PRODUCING 000 TO 111
       int rows = (int) Math.pow(2,n);

       for (i=0; i<rows; i++) {
           for (int j=n-1; j>=0; j--) {
               int pp=(i/(int) Math.pow(2, j))%2;
               System.out.print(pp);
               }      
           System.out.println();
           }
        }
    }
```

This is the output I am getting for the code:

> ```
> |||
> &||
> |&|
> ||&
> &&|
> &|&
> |&&
> &&&
> 000
> 001
> 010
> 011
> 100
> 101
> 110
> 111
> ```

What I need now is to produce a output of series 0|0|0 to 0&0&0,0|0|1 to 0&0&1 and finally upto 1|1|1 to 1&1&1.

Below is the code snippet of what I have tried doing. I have created another function and I have tried to bring in the values from above code that produces string p(having ||| to &&&) and pp(000 to 111) and take each character and store them in **a which is array** :

```
for (int i=0; i < pp.length(); i++){
        if (i % 2 != 0){
          a = pp.substring(0,i-1) + p.substring(0,i-1) + pp.substring(i, pp.length())+p.substring(i, pp.length());
        }
      }
```

But still I am facing error. I don't know where I am going wrong and how to approach to the solution to make the code.

Comment: Would you please post the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a quite hard problem to combine these two very different permutations. Since you program in Java, I highly suggest you to use what Java offers.

This problem can be solved with your custom `Iterable<String>` whos `Iterator<String>` provides you an unique permutation with each `next()` method call. Then use these two iterators (first for 3x`"01"` characters and the second one for 2x`"&|"` characters) and combine their outputs.

Here you go:

1. The custom `Iterable<String>` generating the permutation. Note it extends  `HashSet<String>` which is `Iterable` itself where are the permutations stored. The method `initialize` recursively adds all the permutations to the Set:

   ```
   public class BinaryPermutation extends HashSet<String> {

       private final Iterator<String> iterator;
       private final String token;

       public BinaryPermutation(String token, int n) {
           this.token = token;
           this.initialize("", n);
           this.iterator = super.iterator();
       }

       private void initialize(String string, int iteration) {
           if (iteration == 0) {
              this.add(string);
           } else {
               for (char ch: token.toCharArray()) {
                   initialize(string + Character.toString(ch), iteration - 1);
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Now in the Main class or anywhere create a static method which combines 2 Strings together (ex.: `011`+`|&`=`0|1&1`):

   ```
   private static String combineString(String s1, String s2) {
       String combined = "";
       for (int i=0; i<Math.max(s1.length(), s2.length()); i++) {
           if (i<s1.length()) { combined += Character.toString(s1.charAt(i)); }
           if (i<s2.length()) { combined += Character.toString(s2.charAt(i)); }
       }
       return combined;
   }
   ```
3. Finally perform the calls over 2 custom iterators and combine their outputs:

   ```
   Iterator<String> numbers = new BinaryPermutation("01", 3).iterator();
   Iterator<String> operators = new BinaryPermutation("&|", 2).iterator();

   while (numbers.hasNext()) {
       String number = numbers.next();
       while (operators.hasNext()) {
           String operator = operators.next();
           String permutation = combineString(number, operator);
           System.out.println(permutation);
       }
       operators = new BinaryPermutation("&|", 2).iterator();
   }
   ```

The result is the binary permutation of all the characters as your question states above.